# JTextFields and JTextArea shrinking when inputting large quantity of text into JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, shrink

I have a `JTabbedPane` in a `JDialog` box that uses `GridBagLayout` on all the `JPanels` contained within the pane. On the first panel displayed there is a `JTextArea` (`descTxt`) that is ready to input a film description in. When you input a large amount of text into the `JTextArea` it seems fine up until you click anywhere on the panel that isn't a component (empty grey space) and then all the text fields and text panes shrink to what seems to be size 0.

Here is some example text to paste in and to test:

> During a manned mission to Mars, Astronaut Mark Watney is presumed
>   dead after a fierce storm and left behind by his crew. But Watney has
>   survived and finds himself stranded and alone on the hostile planet.
>   With only meager supplies, he must draw upon his ingenuity, wit and
>   spirit to subsist and find a way to signal to Earth that he is alive.

Here is a runnable example of my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

/**
 *
 * @author Chris
 */
public class AdminWindow extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel adminPanel1, adminPanel2, adminPanel3;
    private JTabbedPane tabPane;
    private GridBagConstraints g1, g2, g3;
    private JLabel idLbl, showLbl, descLbl, ageLbl, imgLbl, timeLbl, screenLbl,
            stanLbl, vipLbl, idLbl1, showLbl1, descLbl1, ageLbl1, imgLbl1, imgName;
    private JTextField idTxt, showTxt, imgTxt, timeTxt, stanTxt, vipTxt,
            idTxt1, showTxt1, imgTxt1;
    private JTextArea descTxt, descTxt1;
    private JComboBox ageCb, ageCb1, screenCb, timeCb, showingCb;
    private JScrollPane descTxtPane, descTxtPane1;
    private ArrayList<String> screenList, timeList, showingList;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel screenModel, timeModel, showingModel;
    private JButton submit, clear, seatSubmit, seatClear, addBtn, subBtn,
            submit1, clear1, imgBtn;
    private double stanPrice, vipPrice;
    private String stanPriceString, vipPriceString, priceExpression, imgString;
    private Pattern p;
    private File dest, chosenFile;

    public AdminWindow() {

        //frame properties
        super(new JFrame("Admin Panel"));
        setTitle("Admin Panel");
        //setSize(Dimensions.getScreenWidth() - 100, Dimensions.getScreenHeight() - 100);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //regular expression validations
        priceExpression = "[0-9]{1,2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}";
        p = Pattern.compile(priceExpression);

        //panel dec
        tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        adminPanel1 = new JPanel();
        adminPanel2 = new JPanel();
        adminPanel3 = new JPanel();
        g1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        g2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        g3 = new GridBagConstraints();

        //label dec
        idLbl = new JLabel("Film ID");
        showLbl = new JLabel("Film Name");
        descLbl = new JLabel("Film Description");
        ageLbl = new JLabel("Age Rating");
        imgLbl = new JLabel("Image");
        idLbl1 = new JLabel("Film ID");
        showLbl1 = new JLabel("Film Name");
        descLbl1 = new JLabel("Film Description");
        ageLbl1 = new JLabel("Age Rating");
        imgLbl1 = new JLabel("Image");
        timeLbl = new JLabel("Showing Times");
        screenLbl = new JLabel("Screen Number");
        stanLbl = new JLabel("Standard Ticket Cost (£)");
        vipLbl = new JLabel("VIP Ticket Cost (£)");
        imgName = new JLabel("filename.jpg");

        //label properties
        imgName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

        //txttfield dec
        idTxt = new JTextField(4);
        showTxt = new JTextField(30);
        descTxt = new JTextArea(4, 30);
        descTxtPane = new JScrollPane(descTxt, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        imgTxt = new JTextField();
        idTxt1 = new JTextField(4);
        showTxt1 = new JTextField(30);
        descTxt1 = new JTextArea(4, 30);
        descTxtPane1 = new JScrollPane(descTxt1, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        imgTxt1 = new JTextField();
        timeTxt = new JTextField(4);
        stanTxt = new JTextField(4);
        vipTxt = new JTextField(4);

        //textfield properties
        idTxt1.setEditable(false);
        descTxt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        descTxt.setLineWrap(true);

        //drop-down dec
        ageCb = new JComboBox();
        ageCb1 = new JComboBox();
        screenCb = new JComboBox();
        timeCb = new JComboBox();
        showingCb = new JComboBox();

        //dropdown properties
        timeCb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 23));

        //buttons
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        submit1 = new JButton("Submit");
        clear1 = new JButton("Clear");
        seatSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        seatClear = new JButton("Show Current");
        addBtn = new JButton("+");
        subBtn = new JButton("-");
        imgBtn = new JButton("Browse..");

        //button properties
        addBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        subBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        addBtn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));
        subBtn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));

        //listeners
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        seatSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        seatClear.addActionListener(this);
        addBtn.addActionListener(this);
        subBtn.addActionListener(this);
        imgBtn.addActionListener(this);


        //fill price text fields with existing prices
        defaultForm();

        //add items to jcombobox
        ageCb.addItem("U");
        ageCb.addItem("12A");
        ageCb.addItem("15");
        ageCb.addItem("18");
        ageCb1.addItem("U");
        ageCb1.addItem("12A");
        ageCb1.addItem("15");
        ageCb1.addItem("18");

        //panel properties

        adminPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adminPanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adminPanel3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adminPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black), "New Showing"));
        adminPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black), "Seat Prices"));
        adminPanel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black), "Edit Showing"));

        //ading panels to tabbed pane
        tabPane.addTab("Add Showings", null, adminPanel1, "Add new showings & showing times");
        tabPane.addTab("Seat Prices", null, adminPanel2, "Change seat prices");
        tabPane.addTab("Edit Showing", null, adminPanel3, "Edit existing showing");

        //-----adding components to pane--------------------------------------!
        g1.gridx = 0;
        g1.gridy = 0;
        g1.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10);
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(idLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel1.add(idTxt, g1);
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(showLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel1.add(showTxt, g1);
        g1.gridwidth = 1;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(descLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel1.add(descTxtPane, g1);
        g1.gridwidth = 1;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(ageLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel1.add(ageCb, g1);
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(imgLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 2;
        adminPanel1.add(imgBtn, g1);
        g1.gridx = 3;
        adminPanel1.add(imgName, g1);
        g1.gridwidth = 1;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx = 0;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(screenLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel1.add(screenCb, g1);
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(timeLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel1.add(timeTxt, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        adminPanel1.add(addBtn, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        adminPanel1.add(timeCb, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        adminPanel1.add(subBtn, g1);
        //buttons
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx = 0;
        g1.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10); //top, right, bottom, left
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(clear, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel1.add(submit, g1);
        g1.gridwidth = 1;

        //------adding components to panel2-----------------------------------!
        //left
        g2.gridx = 0;
        g2.gridy = 0;
        g2.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        g2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel2.add(stanLbl, g2);
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(vipLbl, g2);
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(seatClear, g2);
        //right
        g2.gridy = 0;
        g2.gridx++;
        g2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel2.add(stanTxt, g2);
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(vipTxt, g2);
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(seatSubmit, g2);

        //-----adminpanel3-----------------------------------------------------
        //adding components to panel1
        g3.gridx = 1;
        g3.gridy = 0;
        g3.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10);
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel3.add(showingCb, g3);
        g3.gridwidth = 1;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(idLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel3.add(idTxt1, g3);
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(showLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 5;
        adminPanel3.add(showTxt1, g3);
        g3.gridwidth = 1;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(descLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel3.add(descTxtPane1, g3);
        g3.gridwidth = 1;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(ageLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel3.add(ageCb1, g3);
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;

        //buttons
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx = 0;
        g3.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10); //top, right, bottom, left
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(clear1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel3.add(submit1, g3);
        g3.gridwidth = 1;

        //adding tabbed pane to frame
        this.add(tabPane);
        this.pack();

        //visibility
        setVisible(true);
        tabPane.setVisible(true);

        //actionlisteners
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdminWindow test = new AdminWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == imgBtn) {

            //--JFileChooser, ugly but better to use--
            String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(userDir+"/Desktop");
            int choice = chooser.showDialog(this, "Choose");
            if (choice != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                return;
            }

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            chosenFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            imgName.setText(chosenFile.getName());
            dest = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/iegroup/resources", chosenFile.getName());
            imgString = "resources/" + chosenFile.getName();
            System.out.println(dest.toPath());
        }

        if (e.getSource() == submit) {


        if (e.getSource() == clear ){


        }

        if (e.getSource() == seatSubmit) {

            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == seatClear) {
            defaultForm();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == addBtn) {

            timeModel.addElement(timeTxt.getText());
            timeList.add(timeTxt.getText());
        }
        if (e.getSource() == subBtn) {
            timeModel.removeElement(timeCb.getSelectedItem());
            timeList.remove(timeCb.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }

    private void defaultForm() {

        stanPriceString = String.format("%.2f", stanPrice);
        vipPriceString = String.format("%.2f", vipPrice);
        stanTxt.setText(stanPriceString);
        vipTxt.setText(vipPriceString);
    }

    public void showValidationPrompt(String message) {
        JFrame validFrame = new JFrame();
        validFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(validFrame, message, "Invalid input", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);

    }

    public void showSuccessPrompt(String message) {
        JFrame errorFrame = new JFrame();
        errorFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorFrame, message, "Success", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);

    }
}
```

Please help. This one is very confusing and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem seems to a combination of `setResizable(false)` and `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED` (alright, I just hate unresizable windows).

What's happen is, when you fill the `JTextArea`, it's "adding" the `JScrollPane` into an already "packed" window, so there component's size has changed, then when the container is revalidated, there is no longer enough space left to pack all the fields into at their preferred size, so they are been sized to their minimum size instead, which is typically `0x0` or near enough.

There are a few things you can do to help things along.  You could use `GridBagConstraints#fill` and use `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` for the text fields and `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` for the text area's, what this will do is allow the fields to "fill" and occupy the available space of the column/row regardless of when the cell space is smaller than the component's preferred size.

You might also find `GridBagConstraints#weightx/y` to `1` can help.

And if you're having real trouble, you could simply use `ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` in the `JScrollPane`, which while not pretty, will add in the `JScrollBar` size into the `JScrollPane` when the window is packed

**Updated**

So, basically, I ended up using a combination of `fill` and `weightx/y` for the `JScrollPane`'s and `JTextArea`s

```
g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
g1.weightx = 1;
g1.weighty = 1;
adminPanel1.add(descTxtPane, g1);
g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
g1.weightx = 0;
g1.weighty = 0;
```

For the `JTextField`s I just used `fill` which seems to have stabilised things...

```
g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
adminPanel1.add(idTxt, g1);
g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
```

Which resulted in something like...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class AdminWindow extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel adminPanel1, adminPanel2, adminPanel3;
    private JTabbedPane tabPane;
    private GridBagConstraints g1, g2, g3;
    private JLabel idLbl, showLbl, descLbl, ageLbl, imgLbl, timeLbl, screenLbl,
            stanLbl, vipLbl, idLbl1, showLbl1, descLbl1, ageLbl1, imgLbl1, imgName;
    private JTextField idTxt, showTxt, imgTxt, timeTxt, stanTxt, vipTxt,
            idTxt1, showTxt1, imgTxt1;
    private JTextArea descTxt, descTxt1;
    private JComboBox ageCb, ageCb1, screenCb, timeCb, showingCb;
    private JScrollPane descTxtPane, descTxtPane1;
    private ArrayList<String> screenList, timeList, showingList;
    private DefaultComboBoxModel screenModel, timeModel, showingModel;
    private JButton submit, clear, seatSubmit, seatClear, addBtn, subBtn,
            submit1, clear1, imgBtn;
    private double stanPrice, vipPrice;
    private String stanPriceString, vipPriceString, priceExpression, imgString;
    private Pattern p;
    private File dest, chosenFile;

    public AdminWindow() {

        //frame properties
        setTitle("Admin Panel");
        //setSize(Dimensions.getScreenWidth() - 100, Dimensions.getScreenHeight() - 100);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
//        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //regular expression validations
        priceExpression = "[0-9]{1,2}[.]{1}[0-9]{2}";
        p = Pattern.compile(priceExpression);

        //panel dec
        tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        adminPanel1 = new JPanel();
        adminPanel2 = new JPanel();
        adminPanel3 = new JPanel();
        g1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        g2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        g3 = new GridBagConstraints();

        //label dec
        idLbl = new JLabel("Film ID");
        showLbl = new JLabel("Film Name");
        descLbl = new JLabel("Film Description");
        ageLbl = new JLabel("Age Rating");
        imgLbl = new JLabel("Image");
        idLbl1 = new JLabel("Film ID");
        showLbl1 = new JLabel("Film Name");
        descLbl1 = new JLabel("Film Description");
        ageLbl1 = new JLabel("Age Rating");
        imgLbl1 = new JLabel("Image");
        timeLbl = new JLabel("Showing Times");
        screenLbl = new JLabel("Screen Number");
        stanLbl = new JLabel("Standard Ticket Cost (£)");
        vipLbl = new JLabel("VIP Ticket Cost (£)");
        imgName = new JLabel("filename.jpg");

        //label properties
//        imgName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));

        //txttfield dec
        idTxt = new JTextField(4);
        showTxt = new JTextField(30);
        descTxt = new JTextArea(4, 30);
        descTxtPane = new JScrollPane(descTxt, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        imgTxt = new JTextField();
        idTxt1 = new JTextField(4);
        showTxt1 = new JTextField(30);
        descTxt1 = new JTextArea(4, 30);
        descTxtPane1 = new JScrollPane(descTxt1, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        imgTxt1 = new JTextField();
        timeTxt = new JTextField(4);
        stanTxt = new JTextField(4);
        vipTxt = new JTextField(4);

        //textfield properties
        idTxt1.setEditable(false);
        descTxt.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        descTxt.setLineWrap(true);

        //drop-down dec
        ageCb = new JComboBox();
        ageCb1 = new JComboBox();
        screenCb = new JComboBox();
        timeCb = new JComboBox();
        showingCb = new JComboBox();

        //dropdown properties
//        timeCb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 23));

        //buttons
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        submit1 = new JButton("Submit");
        clear1 = new JButton("Clear");
        seatSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        seatClear = new JButton("Show Current");
        addBtn = new JButton("+");
        subBtn = new JButton("-");
        imgBtn = new JButton("Browse..");

        //button properties
        addBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        subBtn.setFocusPainted(false);
        addBtn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));
        subBtn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));

        //listeners
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        seatSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        seatClear.addActionListener(this);
        addBtn.addActionListener(this);
        subBtn.addActionListener(this);
        imgBtn.addActionListener(this);

        //fill price text fields with existing prices
        defaultForm();

        //add items to jcombobox
        ageCb.addItem("U");
        ageCb.addItem("12A");
        ageCb.addItem("15");
        ageCb.addItem("18");
        ageCb1.addItem("U");
        ageCb1.addItem("12A");
        ageCb1.addItem("15");
        ageCb1.addItem("18");

        //panel properties
        adminPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adminPanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adminPanel3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        adminPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black), "New Showing"));
        adminPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black), "Seat Prices"));
        adminPanel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black), "Edit Showing"));

        //ading panels to tabbed pane
        tabPane.addTab("Add Showings", null, adminPanel1, "Add new showings & showing times");
        tabPane.addTab("Seat Prices", null, adminPanel2, "Change seat prices");
        tabPane.addTab("Edit Showing", null, adminPanel3, "Edit existing showing");

        //-----adding components to pane--------------------------------------!
        g1.gridx = 0;
        g1.gridy = 0;
        g1.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10);
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(idLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    adminPanel1.add(idTxt, g1);
    g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(showLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 4;
        g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        adminPanel1.add(showTxt, g1);
        g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g1.gridwidth = 1;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(descLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 4;
        g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        g1.weightx = 1;
        g1.weighty = 1;
        adminPanel1.add(descTxtPane, g1);
        g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g1.weightx = 0;
        g1.weighty = 0;
        g1.gridwidth = 1;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(ageLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel1.add(ageCb, g1);
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(imgLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 2;
        adminPanel1.add(imgBtn, g1);
        g1.gridx = 3;
        adminPanel1.add(imgName, g1);
        g1.gridwidth = 1;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx = 0;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(screenLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel1.add(screenCb, g1);
        g1.gridx--;
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(timeLbl, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        adminPanel1.add(timeTxt, g1);
        g1.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g1.gridx++;
        adminPanel1.add(addBtn, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        adminPanel1.add(timeCb, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        adminPanel1.add(subBtn, g1);
        //buttons
        g1.gridy++;
        g1.gridx = 0;
        g1.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10); //top, right, bottom, left
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel1.add(clear, g1);
        g1.gridx++;
        g1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g1.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel1.add(submit, g1);
        g1.gridwidth = 1;

        //------adding components to panel2-----------------------------------!
        //left
        g2.gridx = 0;
        g2.gridy = 0;
        g2.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);
        g2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel2.add(stanLbl, g2);
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(vipLbl, g2);
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(seatClear, g2);
        //right
        g2.gridy = 0;
        g2.gridx++;
        g2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        adminPanel2.add(stanTxt, g2);
        g2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g2.gridy++;
        g2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        adminPanel2.add(vipTxt, g2);
        g2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g2.gridy++;
        adminPanel2.add(seatSubmit, g2);

        //-----adminpanel3-----------------------------------------------------
        //adding components to panel1
        g3.gridx = 1;
        g3.gridy = 0;
        g3.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10);
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel3.add(showingCb, g3);
        g3.gridwidth = 1;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(idLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        adminPanel3.add(idTxt1, g3);
        g3.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(showLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 5;
        g3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        adminPanel3.add(showTxt1, g3);
        g3.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g3.gridwidth = 1;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(descLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 4;
        g3.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        g3.weightx = 1;
        g3.weighty = 1;
        adminPanel3.add(descTxtPane1, g3);
        g3.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        g3.weightx = 0;
        g3.weighty = 0;
        g3.gridwidth = 1;
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(ageLbl1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        adminPanel3.add(ageCb1, g3);
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx--;

        //buttons
        g3.gridy++;
        g3.gridx = 0;
        g3.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 10); //top, right, bottom, left
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        adminPanel3.add(clear1, g3);
        g3.gridx++;
        g3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        g3.gridwidth = 4;
        adminPanel3.add(submit1, g3);
        g3.gridwidth = 1;

        //adding tabbed pane to frame
        this.add(tabPane);
        this.pack();

        //visibility
        setVisible(true);
        tabPane.setVisible(true);

        //actionlisteners
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdminWindow test = new AdminWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == imgBtn) {

            //--JFileChooser, ugly but better to use--
            String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(userDir + "/Desktop");
            int choice = chooser.showDialog(this, "Choose");
            if (choice != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                return;
            }

            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            chosenFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            imgName.setText(chosenFile.getName());
            dest = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/iegroup/resources", chosenFile.getName());
            imgString = "resources/" + chosenFile.getName();
            System.out.println(dest.toPath());
        }

        if (e.getSource() == submit) {

            if (e.getSource() == clear) {

            }

            if (e.getSource() == seatSubmit) {

            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == seatClear) {
            defaultForm();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == addBtn) {

            timeModel.addElement(timeTxt.getText());
            timeList.add(timeTxt.getText());
        }
        if (e.getSource() == subBtn) {
            timeModel.removeElement(timeCb.getSelectedItem());
            timeList.remove(timeCb.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }

    private void defaultForm() {

        stanPriceString = String.format("%.2f", stanPrice);
        vipPriceString = String.format("%.2f", vipPrice);
        stanTxt.setText(stanPriceString);
        vipTxt.setText(vipPriceString);
    }

    public void showValidationPrompt(String message) {
        JFrame validFrame = new JFrame();
        validFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(validFrame, message, "Invalid input", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);

    }

    public void showSuccessPrompt(String message) {
        JFrame errorFrame = new JFrame();
        errorFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorFrame, message, "Success", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried fiddling around with GridBagConstraints#fill and weighty/x but couldn't get it to work without fault.

I have resorted to always showing the verticle scroll bar as it has provided me with a quick fix, however like you said not the prettiest. Going to leave this open for a while to see if someone can nail it, if not, I will accept this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: I've finally had chance to further play around with and used a combination of `fill` and `weightx/y` to stabilise the UI, see what you think